# Ubuntu 18.04 GeForce 820m Nvidia 430

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I have a laptop with a GeForce 820m graphics card, which according to the Nvidia website is compatible with the Nvidia driver version 430, which I would like to set up for Vulkan, however it's not showing up as available, only the 340 version. I have oibaf graphics drivers and xorg edgers PPAs enabled. Previously I had `pkcs#7 signature not signed` issues which are still present in the logs, but now the system at least starts and I have 3D acceleration since I added `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to grub. Is there any way to get the later 430 Nvidia driver?

Answer (score 3):

No, Nvidia stopped supporting 820m since 390.xx. 820m has 450 drivers available both on windows and linux, but it is fake. Max version of 820m on windows in 391.xx and on linux is 390xx.

This GPU works best on gdm, boot Ubuntu 20.04 with nomodeset (search google what is nomodeset). Connect to wifi and open terminal. Enter `sudo service gdm stop`. You will get black screen. Press Ctrl + Alt + F4. After that enter your credentials and enter `sudo apt install nvidia-340`. After an install enter `sudo reboot`. Make sure your GPU works by entering Nvidia settings in App Menu. If it works, you can install 390xx. Go to terminal and enter `sudo service gdm stop`, press Ctrl + Alt + F4 and enter your credentials. After that enter `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`. Press Enter. Then enter `sudo apt update`. After that enter `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`. After an installation completed, enter `sudo reboot`. And you successfully installed 390xx. I did it my self on my Inspiron 3443 with 820m graphics and it works perfectly. Im happy

Source: If you try to install driver higher than 390xx, it will give a 820m is not supported warning

Comment: Good luck making it working lol

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Cuz nvidia didnot add 820m in 390xx+. You simply cant install it. Try to open Windows 395xx for example and search for 820m ID. Exactly you wont find any, even tho it is "supported"

Comment: Yeah it states, but it wont work. Cuz i own 2 laptops with 820m. When installing anything higher than 390xx it says that 820m is a legacy GPU and needs a legacy driver. Legacy driver is 390xx or lower. I can even send a imgur if you dont belive. Nvidia just "forgot" remove 820m from support list.

Comment: You just simply cant install anything higher that 390 on this GPU. You simply cant, that is an answer from an 820m owner, or it is not enough? All you did just down voted my answer without checking if it works, even tho people did it before you

Comment: You can also ask a new question about this, since there are no upvoted or accepted answers.  You can link to this question if it helps provide context.  Providing additional details about the exact problems you encounter when trying to install the driver will increase the chances that someone will know the answer. Perhaps we can figure out how to get it working after all?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the driver directly from NVIDIA's driver download page.

Here is a link to the [proprietary NVIDIA driver v. 430](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/149138/en-us).

You can verify that your particular GPU is supported by this version by reviewing the "Supported Products" tab.

Comment: That is a really bad advice. Why not install a driver from the repos?